# JavaScript loop and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am very new to JavaScript and struggling through a book and completing exercises.

Can someone help explain to me what is happening in this loop and what is being stored in the array at the end?

I understand that it is setting image.src to "href" value in the HTML, but why does it need link before getAtribute?
Where is it storing the "href" and the "title"?

```
"use strict";
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var imageCache = [];

var i, link, image;
for ( i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    link = links[i];
    image = new Image();
    image.src = link.getAttribute("href");
    image.title = link.getAttribute("title");
    imageCache[imageCache.length] = image;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help! This community has been a lifesaver while working though this.

Comment: You should show us where you define `links` your code is uncompleted...

Comment: it's interesting that the last line does `imageCache[imageCache.length] = image` when it could just do `imageCache.push(image)` which will automatically add an item to the end of the array

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki 
Sorry!

`var links = listNode.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Is there a benefit from using `imageCache[imageCache.length] = image`?

Answer (score 1):

> but why does it need link before getAtribute

If you google [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), you can see that it is a method called on a HTML element. So `links` seems to be an array of HTML elements (probably link elements).

> Where is it storing the "href" and the "title"?

It stores them as properties of this object: `image = new Image()`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.

Sorry I forgot to include this in the snippet:

var links = listNode.getElementsByTagName("a");

Does the above store all the items on the list with a tag of "a" in an array?

Comment: @AshleySullivan yes, roughly it is like that; all "a" items beneath listNode. It creates array of image objects where each image holds some properties of those "a" elements.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment you didn't show us what the `links` array looks like. However, assuming it's an array of DOM element links, here's a walkthrough of that code:

```
"use strict";
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var imageCache = [];

var i, link, image;
//looping through every element of links array
for ( i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    link = links[i]; //this is the link we're at in the loop, making it easier to reference
    image = new Image(); //creating a new Image element
    image.src = link.getAttribute("href"); //set the src attribute of the image to the href of the link
    image.title = link.getAttribute("title"); //set the title of the image to the title of the link
    imageCache[imageCache.length] = image; //put the image in the imageCache array for use later
}
```

That being said, I think you might look into [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as an alternative way to transform the one array of links into another array of images.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. 
Yes, links[] is an array of DOM elements. Sorry for not posting that.
So when it sets the src attribute of the image to the href of the link and sets the title of the image to the title of the link, it stores that information as well with the image in the imageCache array?
Thanks,

Comment: @AshleySullivan you are correct. You can always throw a `console.log(imageCache)` at the end to see what `imageCache` contains in the console